# Google Maps API cannot reference Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi every time i try to reference a Marker of a Marker list the browser see the marker as undifined every time:

```
**function Change_Marker_Color_In_Array_Delivery(num, markers, dir_end) {
    var dir = "icons\\mapiconscollection-markers\\" + dir_end;
    Markers_Delivery[num] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Markers_Delivery[num].getPosition(),
        map: map,
        icon: dir
    });
}

function Change_Marker_Color(marker) {

    var dir = 'icons\mapiconscollection-markers\footprint.png';
    marker.setIcon(dir);

}**
```

im trying to change the marker icon

with setIcon is undifined
whit getPosition (markers[num].getPosition()) or (Markers_Delivery[num].getPosition()) is undifined

Strange... them i get stuck

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I get it right!!! var dir = 'icons\mapiconscollection-markers\footprint.png'; need double \\ instead of just one var dir = 'icons\\mapiconscollection-markers\\footprint.png';